# Clear localForage on session end

Tags: javascript, session-storage, localforage

Is it possible to get [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) cleared when session ends, much like in sessionStorage? But without sessionStorage limitation of 5Mb

Answer (score 0):

Use `.clear()`. [Libary documentation](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-clear)

Comment: But when user closes a tab and his session ends I wont have a chance to `.clear()` the storage

Comment: I don't think you can detect the session's end correctly. Even if you're using `onbeforeunload ` you can't for sure call `.clear()` because the user might have navigated to another link. Usually session expiration is detected not on tab close but when the token on server expires.